# Node wrapper to start a terminal application like vim, emacs, tmux

Tags: node.js, vim, emacs, terminal, tmux

**TLDR**; how can I run a node process from the terminal, start a process from node, exit the node process and have the process be *attached* to the parent terminal?

I am writing a node terminal application which should end by starting a new terminal application (e.g. `vim`, `emacs`, `tmux`). I want this application to run as if is was executed manually in the terminal that started the node application.

My current *workaround* for `tmux` is to run the node application, which sets up a new `tmux` session and echoes a `tmux attach-session` command just before the application exists. The user can then type this command manually in the terminal and execute it. Now the tmux session runs *attached* to the terminal.

I would want to move the *attach* command into the node application, but have the same end results. I.e. the node application terminates and the `tmux` session runs attached to the terminal. This seems to me to be required to do the same for applications like `emacs`, `vim`, etc. Where I cannot decouple the setup and attach. (For all I know `vim` and `emacs` can handle this decoupling, and I would be interested in knowing, but the original question asks for a general solution for any terminal application).

By *attached*, I mean as if the command/program was executed manually in the terminal.

Comment: From what you describe, you're looking for POSIX `exec`, which replaces the current process with another one. Node doesn't implement it, but you're in luck - there's a module [`kexec`](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-kexec), which lets you use it.

Comment: @Amadan Great, that works perfectly :D Would you like to turn it into an answer so that I can mark it as accepted? If not I can write up the answer with examples myself. :)

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POSIX `exec` solves this problem as @Amadan has commented above. This solution does not work on windows.

The following snippet shows an example of how to do this with the [`kexec`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kexec) module.

```
const kexec = require("kexec");

kexec("emacs -nw");
```